# Android tts in talk back mode

Tags: android, text-to-speech, talkback

I try to speak phrase consecutive in tts. In onDone() method my syntezator start speak next phrase. But in talkback mode tss stoped on accessebility event. Is the way to detect end of accessebility event and restore tts playing?